# Downloading file from Siebel CRM

Tags: c#, .net, automation, siebel

I am trying to download a file from Siebel CRM using web requests, repeating user actions in a browser. I pre-record the browser session traffic using Fiddler and then replicate web requests. In the browser, clicking on the file download link downloads the file in popup-window. But when sending the same request via HttpWebRequest, it returns data with another URI, upon request of which I get a message that a parallel session is open, which is prohibited.
The SWEC ([Siebel Web Extension Click count](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/load-testing-siebel-applications-using-visual-studio/)) is thoughtlessly copied from a pre-recorded browser session. Can anyone give advice on how to work with downloads in Siebel CRM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For successful downloading require to replicate ALL service requests since authorization.

---

**UPDATE**

No need to repeat all requests occurring in the web interface. It is enough to complete the first service request with the original `SWEC` parameter (in my case `SWEC=2`), and after that you can execute the requests related to the file download, replacing the original `SWEC` values with 3, 4, etc.